# Adding single and double tap gesture on subview of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`. I am trying to add Single Tap gesture to view it in full size and double tap gesture to like. Here is my code for that:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *aSingleTapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SingleTapGestureRecognizer:)] autorelease];
    aSingleTapGesture.delegate = self;
    aSingleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.imgProductImage addGestureRecognizer:aSingleTapGesture];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *aDoubleTapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapGestureRecognizer:)] autorelease];
    aDoubleTapGesture.delegate = self;
    aDoubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [cell.imgProductImage addGestureRecognizer:aDoubleTapGesture];
```

It only calls single tap gesture and double tap gesture was never being called. Than I used `require to fail` on single tap gesture.

```
   [aSingleTapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:aDoubleTapGesture];
```

Well, using this code I am able to call single and double tap gesture both, But the problem is the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is also being called. I don't want to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath if my gestures are being called. As of my understanding it is being called because single tap gesture is waiting for double tap gesture mean while didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called.

Any help please.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967125/how-to-disable-user-interaction-with-cell-in-uitableview

Comment: Thanks.. If so than I need to check if I tapped on Image or tapped on some other portion of TableViewCell. How can I check that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIButton instead of UIImageView in tableview cell. Use following code for getting single and double tap.

```
//add target for your UITableViewCell's button

[aBtnThumbObj addTarget:self action:@selector(btnThumbClickDouble:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];

[aBtnThumbObj addTarget:self action:@selector(btnThumbClickSingle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)btnThumbClickSingle:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(singleTapOnButtonSelector:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.2];
}
-(void)btnThumbClickDouble:(UIButton*)sender
{   
   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTapOnButtonSelector:) object:sender];
//Your implementation for double tap
}
-(void)singleTapOnButtonSelector:(UIButton*)sender
{
//Your implementation for single tap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set selection style for your cell as

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

And then just don't implement your -tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Yes.. But I need to implement `-tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` as If user select a part other than the image it should perform a push on another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code work for me:

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```